# Is it a common practice to copy code from the .net libraries?

Tags: c#, .net

I once saw a project in which at the root element the programmer had folders like `MS.Internal` or `Microsoft.*`. He had copied the decompiled source from the .net classes in classes not marked as sealed to modify them or to be able to access them or modifying them in another way.

I wondered wheter this is the common way if there is no workaround for such situations or whether this is even legal?

If marking the classes as sealed and internal should protect us; then why are classes and Methods like `BooleanBoxes` or `DoubleUtil.IsNaN(double)` internal? They are good for optimizations.

Comment: What could possibly make someone do that? For that matter.. what amount of code are they copying that amounts to it's own folder structure? What a strange practice...

Comment: Without commenting on the legality of doing this, I'd say that it's quite uncommon. If one needs to subclass a `sealed` class, chances are you are doing something incorrectly.

Comment: might he have been porting code from WPF to Silverlight or vice-versa and wanted to add missing stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not common practice, but in fact (very) bad practice. Depending on the license of the code (work) that was decompiled it may or may not be legal in terms of copyright laws.

When applied to a class, the `sealed` modifier prevents other classes from inheriting from it. The author of a class marked as `sealed` did not want anyone to inherit from it.

You can also use the `sealed` modifier on a method or property that overrides a virtual method or property in a base class. This enables you to allow classes to derive from your class and prevent them from overriding specific virtual methods or properties.